# Why can't I use the STDdraw and STDAudio classes at the same time in java?

Tags: java, audio, draw, stddraw

I am working a program that plays sounds by clicking keyboard keys. I have gotten it to work, however when I try to visualize that sound, The sound stops playing. So I can either play the sounds, or make the waves but not both. How do I make them both work?

```
    public class GuitarHeroVisualizer { 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      String keyboard = "q2we4r5ty7u8i9op-[=zxdcfvgbnjmk,.;/' ";
      GuitarString[] strings = new GuitarString[37];
      int x = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        strings[i] = new GuitarString(440.0 * Math.pow(1.05956, i - 23));
      }
      while (true) {
        if (StdDraw.hasNextKeyTyped()) {
            char key = StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();
            int j = keyboard.indexOf(key);
            if (j != -1) {
                strings[j].pluck();
            }
        }
         // compute the superposition of samples
         //double sample = stringA.sample() + stringC.sample();
         double sample = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
            sample += strings[i].sample();
         }

        // play the sample on standard audio

        if(sample != 0)
        {
            StdDraw.setXscale(0, 90);
            StdDraw.line(x, 0, x + 1, sample);
            StdDraw.line(x + 1, sample, x + 2, 0);
            x += 2;
        }

        StdAudio.play(sample);

        for (int i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
            strings[i].tic();
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Other two classes:

```
    public class GuitarString {
RingBuffer buffer;
int N;
int time = 0;
public GuitarString(double frequency) {
    N = (int)(44100/frequency);
    buffer = new RingBuffer(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        buffer.enqueue(0);
    }
}

public GuitarString(double[] init) {
    buffer = new RingBuffer(init.length + 1);
    N = init.length + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < init.length; i++) {
        buffer.enqueue(init[i]);
    }
}

public void pluck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        buffer.dequeue();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        buffer.enqueue(Math.random()-0.5);
    }
}

public void tic() {
    time++;
    double first = buffer.dequeue();
    double avg = (buffer.peek() + first) / 2;
    buffer.enqueue(avg * .994);
}

public double sample() {
    return buffer.peek();
}

public int time() {
    return time;
}
```

}

next:

```
    public class RingBuffer {
double[] nums;
int capacity;
int size = 0;
int first = 0;
int last = 0;
public RingBuffer(int cap) {
    capacity = cap;
    nums = new double[cap];
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (size() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    if (size() == capacity) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void enqueue(double x) {
    if (isFull()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Queue is full.");
    }
    nums[last] = x;
    last++;
    if(last == capacity) {last = 0;}
    size++;
}

public double dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Queue is empty.");
    }
    double num = nums[first];
    first++;
    if(first == capacity) {first = 0;}
    size--;
    return num;
}

public double peek() {
    return nums[first];
}
```

}

here is the std classes:
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdAudio.html

Comment: This is just a theory but I believe the problem might have something to do with the threads overlapping.

Comment: stddraw is for kindergarden classes - grow up and use regular java - forget the princeton nonsense